# Port forwarding broken with installation of access point

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I recently purchased an Asus RT-N12B1.  It has an external hardware switch which allows the router to operate in different modes.  I put in access point mode.  Then I connected an ethernet cable from a LAN port on my Verizon supplied Actiontec MI424WR-GEN2 E router to a LAN port on the access point and turned off the wireless in the router.

I have dynamic DNS setup and port forwarding setup in the router to forward from port 50000 to 192.168.1.2:22 which is a server plugged into a LAN port on the router.  This is no longer working since adding the AP and disabling wireless on the primary router.  Any ideas why or how to debug?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your setup is okay. These problems normally come up when the cable in the WAN port on the access point. You have to make sure the access point has all routing/firewall/NAT functions disabled.

Are you able to connect to the internet and your router when you are connected through wireless? (remove any ethernetcables before testing)

With DHCP enabled on your PC, which IP adress are you getting through LAN and wireless? Is it the same address, a different adress in the same subnet, or a different subnet? Are the IP adresses both configured for forwarding in the router?

Comment: I am able to connect to the internet wirelessly. The IP address on my laptop is 192.168.1.153, the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 and the default gateway is 192.168.1.1. Or were you asking about the server on my network that I'm trying to connect to? What do you mean "are the IP addresses both configured for forwarding"? Which two IPs and how would they be configured? I only have one IP setup for port forwarding in the router.

Comment: What is your IP address when connected through wireless, and what is it through ethernetcable? Is the server still connected through ethernet or is it wireless now?

Are you able to ping 192.168.1.2 from your computer?

Comment: As I said, the IP address when connected through wireless is 192.168.1.153.  The server is connected via ethernet to the router as described in the post.  I can connect to 192.168.1.2:22 from the laptop.